# How to display text/image in a report depending on buildoption?

Tags: reporting-services, configuration

I would like to display a text or an image on my reports depending on buildoption, ie debug/release so my users are never confused about what environment they are in.

I work in visual studio 2013. Is it possible to use app.config or something similiar for reports?

Comment: You are talking about the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio 2013, is that right?

Comment: In part yes. Depending on what buildoption I use (which can be defined through configuration manager) I wan't to display different things on my report(s).



In c# I would have a app.config file what I could transform and access it's values. For example by using: Properties.Settings.Default.SystemEnvironment

I started to play around and now using an expresison in a textbox that looks like this:
=IIf(Globals!ReportFolder = "/Test", "TEST" , "")

Which in part works, but doesn't feel like a good solution.

Comment: The reports are not "built" specifically in `Debug` or `Release`, they are just deployed to the report server and the configurations like `Debug`/`Release` are just to store deployment information in the project file, the ones you see in the report project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked this one out for myself, sort of.

I added a background image and used expression (Globals!ReportFolder) if I should display it or not.

Expression was: =IIF((Globals!ReportFolder = "/Test"), "TestBackground", "")

Thanks to Sébastien Sevrin for pointing out that reports arent built and I need to look into deploysettings.

Comment: Glad you could resolve your issue. Note that `Globals!ReportFolder` is null if you preview the report in BIDS. Another option could be to add a hidden parameter to specify the target environment, and then to set it in the linked reports or the report itself